# WPF WindowsFormsHost creates fuzzy text

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, text-rendering, windowsformshost

I am hosting a winforms `DataGridView` inside a `WindowsFormsHost` on a WPF Window. Functionality is fine, but the text in the grid cells looks a little more fuzzy. Normally WinForms text has very little antialiasing.

How can I get the `DataGridView` text to look as it normally would on a Windows `Form`, or at least be sharper? I have tried playing with the `TextOptions.TextFormattingMode`and `SnapsToDevicePixels`settings of the `WindowsFormsHost`, but don't see any difference.

As an example of what I mean here are two screenshots:

`Datagridview` inside a WPF `WindowsFormsHost`:

[image: DataGridView in WindowsFormHost]

`DataGridView` in Windows Forms:

[image: DataGridView in WinForms]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The appearance of hosted WinForms/Win32 content should not be affected by WPF.  There is an "airspace" limitation that dictates that a single window pixel can only be owned by a single graphics API, and it can only be drawn by that API.  Hence, WinForms content is drawn by WinForms/GDI+, even when hosted by WPF.  This explains why hosted content will be drawn on top of any WPF content in the same window, even if the WPF content is positioned in front of it.

Changing WPF rendering properties like `TextFormattingMode` cannot affect the appearance of interop content.  You should be looking at the layout/rendering properties of the hosted WinForms content.

**Update**

Presumably the fuzzy effect is do to WPF defaulting to grayscale AA for the `DataGridView`. In the `Paint` and/or `CellPainting` events of the `DataGridView`, setting the graphics text hint to cleartype:

```
 e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit
```

eliminated most of the fuzziness.

Comment: That makes sense, but when I place a `DataGridView` on a Windows Form, and then put that same `DataGridView` in a `WindowsFormHost` in WPF Window, the difference in text rendering is very noticeable.

Comment: Odd.  `WindowsFormsHost` sets up translations between *some* WPF and WinForms properties like `Foreground`, `Background`, `FontFamily`, etc. (see `WindowsFormsHostPropertyMap`).  But I don't see any that would affect antialiasing.  Perhaps there's a process-wide flag that's being inherited?

Comment: Yes codewise I am doing nothing more than just dumping the grid into the `WindowsFormsHost`, and from above screenshot `FontFamily` looks the same or very similar. This is well out of my depth. But when looking a large grid of fairly small text, the antialiasing becomes kind of annoying, at least on my monitors.

Comment: From the screenshot, it appears to be using grayscale antialiasing (as opposed to ClearType).  I suspect it *is* a process-wide flag, because I seem to remember WPF apps falling back to grayscale AA even if system-wide AA is disabled.

Comment: thanks good to know what's going on at least... any way to turn it off? Or make it better in general?

Comment: My cursory Googling didn't yield any useful results for switching it off programatically.  Maybe set the [`TextRenderingHint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ssazt6bs.aspx) on the WinForms `Graphics` context?  Might require overriding your content's `OnPaint()` method.

Comment: Good news! Using `e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit` gets rid of the fuzzy look. Quite a relief. It was your suggestion so I edited your response and marked as answer.